# How can I locate a ui:inputCheckbox?

Tags: ui, inputcheckboxes, aura-id

hopefully this will be an easy one. I'm iterating through a list to populate a table, and I want to have checkboxes on the table too. I also want to be able to locate the previously chosen checkbox and set its value to false, sort of like a radio button. I made each checkbox unique using a globalId and indexVar:

```
<tbody>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.refactoredData}" var="datum" indexVar="indx">
                        <tr id="{!globalId + indx+'_tr'}">

                            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.checkBoxListener}">

                                <td style="width:60px;"><ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="{!globalId + indx + '_check'}" text="{!indx}" change="{!c.boxChecked}"/></td>{!globalId + indx+'_check'}

                            </aura:if>
```

Then in the controller I grab the index and value:

```
boxChecked : function(component, event, helper) {

    var target = event.getSource();
    var idx = Number(target.get("v.text"));
    var val = target.get("v.value");
    helper.checkBox(component, idx, val);

}
```

Then pass them to the helper where I set an attribute value called prevCheck to the most recently clicked checkbox aura:id, which works. I'm using the prevCheck attribute to locate the checkbox that I want to set false (the last one clicked), only the component.find(id) call always returns undefined:

```
checkBox : function(component, idx, val){

    if(component.get("v.limitCheck")){

        if(component.get("v.prevCheck")){

            var id = component.get("v.prevCheck");

            console.log('datatable checkbox if if, component.find(component.get("v.prevCheck")) = '+component.find(id)+', component.get("v.prevCheck") = '+component.get("v.prevCheck"));

            component.find(id).set("v.value", false);
        }

        component.set("v.prevCheck", component.getGlobalId()+idx+'_check');

    }

    var listener = component.get("v.checkBoxListener");
    var event = $A.get("e.c:SDS_DataTableCheckbox_Event");
    event.setParams({"checkBoxListener": listener, "isCheckedNow" : val, "index" : idx, data : component.get("v.data")[idx]});

    console.log('event firing, listener = '+listener);

    event.fire();

}
```

I don't want to use lightning:input because of the required label, but I can't seem to hunt down this ui:inputCheckbox... any ideas?

Comment: I am guessing because you have used globalId in your aura:id you may have to get the Id of the component using var globalId = cmp.getGlobalId(); https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_ids.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign aura:ids dynamically.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_ids.htm

Comment: opps missed the part he is using aura:id instead of id, good catch